# It's hard to click on Bar button Item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created custom back bar button. And I added an UIview because I have to change position of it within bar.

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtnWhite"];

_backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_backButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
[_backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_backButton.frame = CGRectMake(-4.0, 7.0, 40, 40);

UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-4.0, 7.0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height)];
[view addSubview:_backButton];

UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

But after that I've added UIView it became difficult to click on it.
I've tried to change button area, but it didn't give results.

Comment: More description please.

Comment: You set the view's frame to have backButtonImage width and height - are these set properly when the view is instantiated? Also, you could try making sure the view is not absorbing the touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you specify incorrect frame for `_button` or/and `view` and this changes the tap region. Try to set different background color for `_backButton` and `view`. This will show you if frames are in positions that you expect.

If you try to adjust image position by specifying these frames - its more correct to use properties of [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/) like `imageEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets`.